# Why is there 3 constructor functions in this Code?

Tags: java

I'm try to write my own implementation of OpenSimplex Noise in Javascript.

I am using Kurt Spencer's Implementation as a reference. link: https://gist.github.com/KdotJPG/b1270127455a94ac5d19

But I am confused as to why there is 3 constructor functions...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecnyt.png

Your help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with JS, removed the tag.

Comment: They're constuctor overloads, they simply provide more than one way to create the object.

Comment: (1) Please post code as text, not as a picture of code.  (2) What level of answer are you expecting?  Code has multiple constructors because the author perceived different uses requiring different sets of arguments.  Are you wanting us to deduce the specific uses here?

Comment: Why not? Do you want us to analize the whole project to be able to explain why there are 3 different constructors?

Answer (score 2):

Java allows you to overload methods (constructors included). In this case, the first Constructor `OpenSimplexNoise()`, just goes to the last Constructor `OpenSimplexNoise(long seed)` with a default value.

The second constructor you have already the `perm` as an incoming attribute, which will be part of the `OpenSimplexNoise` object.